# Is there a quickish, straighforward way to measure Transactions Per Second on SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2000, monitoring

The `sys.dm_os_performance_counters` DMV introduced in SQL Server 2005 makes this task somewhat trivial. However, my Google-Fu has been blocked in finding a way to do this in SQL Server 2000.

How can I measure transactions per second in SQL Server 2000?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using the SQL Server Counters in the Windows PerfMon Utility.

[This is for SQL 2005](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2006/12/dba-101-using-perfmon-for-sql-performance-tuning/) but the instructions provide the gist of things for you.